# How to create a cloth that keeps its shape

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, parent

[image: Like in this picture the clothing has this shape, but when I apply clothing stimulations it does not stay.]I have made a piece of clothing that is textured, but when I apply cloth stimulations it loses its shape when animating. Is there a way that I can make this piece of clothing just bend along with the body instead of losing its shape when it wrinkles up?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot so we can see what you mean?

Comment: @user20352 Sure

Comment: the purpose of cloth objects is mainly of having a shape that behaves like cloths, so it _should_ change its shape. You can "pin" some vertex group to make some part of the simulated cloth "fixed". Anyway, even from the image, I can't get how is wrong for you... maybe detail what kind of object is and how should it behave as a cloth.

Comment: @m.ardito I didn't think to pin that part of the clothing. I will give it a try